# Extract categorical data from dummy features

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to combine 4 categorical columns into 1 with pandas melt, but it creates 3 duplicates of each row (giving me 4x more rows).

```
dat = pd.DataFrame({'Name':('Tom','Pete','Mark','Steve'),
                    'Type1':(0,1,0,0),
                   'Type2':(1,0,0,0),
                   'Type3':(0,0,0,0),
                   'Type4':(0,0,0,0)})
dat = pd.melt(dat, id_vars='Name', 
              value_vars=('Type1', 'Type2', 'Type3', 'Type4'), value_name='type')



Name    variable    type
0   Tom     Type1   0
1   Pete    Type1   1
2   Mark    Type1   0
3   Steve   Type1   0
4   Tom     Type2   1
5   Pete    Type2   0
6   Mark    Type2   0
7   Steve   Type2   0
8   Tom     Type3   0
9   Pete    Type3   0
10  Mark    Type3   0
11  Steve   Type3   0
12  Tom     Type4   0
13  Pete    Type4   0
14  Mark    Type4   0
15  Steve   Type4   0
```

Another problem I have, which I guess can't be resolved with melt is replacing all of the rows where the value is 0 for all Types with 'None' - but that can probably be done with a simple query - fixing the duplicates is my worry for now. Unless I shouldn't be using melt?

What I'm trying to get is: column with a Type1 or 2 or 3 or 4. So in this case:

```
    Name    Type
0   Tom     Type2
1   Pete    Type1
2   Mark    Type3
3   Steve   Type3
```

Where last 2 would preferably turn to 'None' as these 2 names don't have a type assigned to them. (Hope I'm not going mad and it makes sense to someone other than just me).

Comment: You need to provide your expected output.

Comment: Where are the duplicates?

Comment: Sorry, edited the main post

Comment: @Coolkidscandie can each name have more than one type?

Comment: @Chris - No. I've got a dataframe of about 2000 dogs and only 5-10% of them actually have any category. So rather than having 4 columns where most of them are NaNs, I wanted to have 1 with either just the name of the category (if they have any) or NaN if they don't belong to any category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### `idxmax`

```
dat = pd.DataFrame({'Name':('Tom','Pete','Mark','Steve'),
                'Type1':(0,1,0,0),
               'Type2':(1,0,0,0),
               'Type3':(0,0,0,0),
               'Type4':(0,0,0,0)})

df = dat.loc[:,'Type1':].replace(0, np.nan)
df.idxmax(axis=1).to_frame(name='Type').set_index(dat.Name)

         Type
Name        
Tom    Type2
Pete   Type1
Mark     NaN
Steve    NaN
```

Comment: Will this give me a way of replacing any rows where the Name doesn't belong in any category with NaN or 0 or anything like that? If i replace it now, all Type1 will be replaced.

Comment: @Coolkidscandie please consider marking the answer as correct so I know it help you

Comment: I will once I get to test it - sorry, I'm not able to access my file now. I'll have to go around setting the index, as there are more columns, but I'm sure I'll find something. For now, thank you. When I get to check it, I'll mark it

Comment: so this code is giving me TypeError: reduction operation 'argmax' not allowed for this dtype

Comment: Hi @Coolkidscandie are you using the same dataframe? I just tried again and it runs for me, so unless you have an outdated version of pandas it should work fine

Comment: I used a different way, forgot I have key words included in a different column, used str.extract. Melt function just stuck with me and I thought this was the right way, rather than look for simpler solution. Thanks anyway.